# Is there any way to determine if a Steam game is multiplayer, either using the Steam web api or otherwise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, steam, steam-web-api

I am attempting, via the Steam web api, to get a list of a user's owned games (successful), determine which of those games is multiplayer, and return that info. I am using `requests` and parsing the `json` response to search for mentions of "multiplayer." However, `GetOwnedGames` does not seem to return any applicable responses for my use case. I've even tried `GetSchemaForGame` to check game achievements, but this too does not contain any relevant "categories" by which I can determine whether a game is multiplayer. I am happy to share my code, but I believe (maybe foolishly) it is working as is intended and that the information I need is simply not available by this method.

Are there any other possible avenues to determine whether a game is multiplayer? I suppose I could parse app IDs for the games owned and somehow check a third party Steam database for a multiplayer tag, but I had hoped the Steam api would provide an avenue for this.

Any and all help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get game tags with [steam cmd](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options) (command app_info_print). Of the ready-made solutions for getting json information about the game, i.e. tags, I can offer this https://www.steamcmd.net/#docs or [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/steamcmd/api).

[Json tags id](https://files.catbox.moe/96bty7.json) (there may not be all, tags can be added over time) I got from [steamdb](https://steamdb.info/tags/) although they do not allow it.